# Compilation error regarding pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I keep getting runtime error and i am unable to see the flaw please help, this was a submisson i made to uva online problem 482 permutation arrays

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=423

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
struct goof
{
    int i;
    string num;
} f[10000];
bool cpr(goof x, goof y)
{
    if (x.i < y.i) return true;
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    bool blank = false;
    while (t--)
    {
        getchar();
        char st[10000];
        gets(st);
        char* p = strtok(st, " ");
        int d = 0;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            f[d].i = atoi(p);
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
            d++;
        }
        char sc[10000];
        gets(sc);
        char* q;
        q = strtok(st, " ");
        d = 0;
        while (q != NULL)
        {
            f[d].num = q;
            q = (NULL, " ");
            d++;
        }
        sort(f, f + d, cpr);
        if (blank) printf("\n");
        blank = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            cout << f[j].num << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a rumtime error Runtime error

Comment: For formatting your code: use 4 spaces for each indent, don't use tabs, remove multiple consecutive blank lines. We should not have to page down to see the next line of code. *Readable* code examples make me want to look closer.

Comment: Considering `gets` is going to be removed in C++14 because it's so easy to induce a buffer overrun with it, it's not a wise choice. Use `std::getline`.

Comment: Looks like a typo, you forgot to type `strtok` here `q = (NULL, " ");`;

Comment: I think the warning and error messages are pretty clear. Did you actually *read* them?

Comment: grab the correct indented code from here http://pastebin.com/8b92Kagn

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour thank you i corrected the typo but i still get a run time error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include header `<string>` because you are using class `std::string`

The main error is that you omitted function name in line

```
q = (NULL, " ");
```

There must be

```
q = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

As for function `gets` then it is excluded form C/C++ Standards and the compiler issues a corresponding warning though it is not an error.

Instead of `gets` use standard function `std::getline`

Comment: vlad mosco thanks  I corrected it but still I get a runtime error ...so pls have a look